# ImportError: cannot import name 'types' from 'telebot' (C:\.....\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
```

Получаю ошибку:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'types' from 'telebot'
>   (C:.....\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telebot__init__.py)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вероятнее всего имеет место путаница с названиями.

`import telebot`, но `pip install pyTelegramBotApi`, а не `pip install telebot`.

https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/ != https://pypi.org/project/telebot/

Comment: `pip uninstall telebot`. Благодарить здесь принято отметкой ответа как решение)

Comment: Спасибо большое долго над этим долбался!

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло! ;) Хорошего дня!

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема ушла после команды

```
pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Answer (score 0):

открываем setting (ctrl+alt+s) ищем python interpreter выбираем pip ищем pyTelegramBotAPI устанавливаем (я ещё и telebot установил) (пишу в pycharm)